# How can I "wrap" lists so that I view all of them on on screen (desktop) rather than scrolling horizontally?

Tags: trello

Love Trello and use it to track projects (each project is a list).

Is there a way to "wrap" the lists so that all appear on the canvas rather than scrolling to the right?

Answer (score 2):

If you make your window much smaller, Trello will adapt and list the lists vertically. This is mostly for mobile devices, but it also works for any browser. There's no other way to list lists vertically though.

Answer (score 2):

[Vertical Trello - Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vertical-trello/aldklnbenbdgfgfbflalmlddkkndgnlc)

Very late response, but I came across this question when I was searching for a solution, so maybe it will help others. I didn't find anything so I created the extension above.

(Hopefully in future I'll have some time to make it actually "wrap" the lists to maximize the useful area, but for now it just lists them vertically.)

Comment: Great extension, but it resets on page refresh. Would be nice to remember the layout.

Answer (score 1):

For everything-but-Chrome I use *TamperMonkey* with a Trello-wrap-n-stack  userscript I put on Github:

### How to use in Safari, Firefox, MS Edge

1. Install [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) from Your-Browser's Extensions gallery
2. Navigate to https://gist.github.com/chrisfcarroll/72af8356b189dbdaaaea
3. Assure yourself it does nothing malicious. If you're not a fluent JavaScript speaker, phone a friend.
4. Click on the `Raw` button

On a good day, TamperMonkey will automatically jump in and ask if you want to install it. Otherwise, download it or save it to desktop and install manually via the TamperMonkey control panel.

### Chrome

Chrome can run userscripts without needing TamperMonkey, but very sensibly prevents you from installing them from the interwebs. You can install by downloading it to localmachine first, and then drag into Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can use the [Custom Style Script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-style-script/?src=search) plugin and add a rule for trello.com with the following CSS

```
.list-wrapper {
height: initial;
margin: 8px;
}

#board {
white-space: initial;
}
```

It's a hack that might fail at any moment, but is working for me for now.

Comment: Best solution as it is simplest and safest (CSS).

Answer (score 0):

This works from the developer tools in Chrome: it could be made into a bookmarklet or user script.

```
var sheet = $('<style>', {
    type:'text/css',
    text: ''
}).appendTo('head')[0].sheet;
sheet.insertRule([
    '.list {',
    'flex-basis: auto;',
    'margin-bottom: 1ex;',
'}'].join('\n'), 0);
sheet.insertRule([
'#board {',
    'flex-wrap: wrap;',
    'flex-direction: column;',
'}'].join('\n'), 1)
```

(PUBLIC DOMAIN)